# How to add "http://" to a string (if missing)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string `[currentTweet pic]` that is supposed to be the URL to a picture (parsed from an XML file). The problem is some of the links are missing the "http://" in the URL so some pictures don't appear. How can I add the "http://" where it's missing?

Any help is strongly appreciated! thx

Comment: How do you know it should be `http://` and not `https://`?

Answer (score 13):

I assume you mean a `NSString` here, as opposed to a `NSURL`.

```
NSString *picURL = [currentTweet pic];
if (![picURL hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {
    picURL = [@"http://" stringByAppendingString:picURL];
}
```

Not sure if twitter ever uses `https` for pic urls, but you should possibly also check for `https://` just to be sure.